# Manipulating a ListView's items contained in a ViewHolder - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, listview

I am experiencing some weird behaviour in my code you'll find below. I have a button in each row of my `ListView` and if it is clicked, I want to gray out the row and hide the button. To make the change permanent I have set a property in the custom `ViewHolder` so the changes are persistent.

However, clicking the button on, say item 1, will also apply the changes to item 6. On other items it affects no other row or it affects more than one row. I suspect it has something to do with me declaring some `final` variables but I cannot be sure. I tried implementing different solutions (reducing the number of final variables, using different variables, ect) but nothing really seems to work.

I am in need of some assistance. Thank you!

```
public class FruitLoopsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<FruitLoopsNode> provider;
    private Activity parent;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param parent 
     *      The parent activity of the fragment using the FruitLoop. Needed as the adapter will
     *      be used in a fragment which only its parents has access to the data providers. 
     */
    public FruitLoopsAdapter(Activity parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        provider = ((Box)parent).getFruitLoops();
    }

    /**
     * Method returning the size of the underlying data provider.
     * @return
     *      The size of the data provider.
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
            return provider.size();
    }

    /**{@inheritDoc}*/
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
            return provider.get(position);
    }

    /**{@inheritDoc}*/
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
            return position;
    }

    /**
     * Method building the composite custom view and returning it as one view.
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentViewGroup)
    {       
            FruitLoopsViewHolder viewHolder;
            final FruitLoopsNode FruitLoopsNode = provider.get(position);

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_FruitLoops, null);

                    viewHolder = new FruitLoopsViewHolder(
                                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time),
                                    (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.consume),
                                    (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail),
                                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_title),
                                    (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_brief),
                                    (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar));
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                    viewHolder = (FruitLoopsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    determinePresentationMode(convertView, viewHolder);
            }

            /** [Omitted some code setting many of the fields above to] */

            final Button button = viewHolder.getButton();
            final View finalConvertView = convertView;
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                            button.setEnabled(false);
                            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            finalConvertView.setAlpha(0.5f);
                            finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    }
            });

            /**
             * As using a final viewHolder to set the value inside the onClick() method of the 
             * button will cause the images not to update anymore, investigating the alpha value
             * of the convertView seemed the only easy way to get there. Also, as it is a float, 
             * I want to leave a bit of extra padding in the test.
             */
            if(finalConvertView.getAlpha() < 0.9)
            {
                    viewHolder.setConsumed(true);
            }

    return convertView;
    }

    private void determinePresentationMode(View convertView, FruitLoopsViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
            if(viewHolder.wasConsumed())
            {
                    convertView.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to reset the alpha to initial state if `wasConsumed()` is false.

Something like:

```
private void determinePresentationMode(View convertView, FruitLoopsViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
            if(viewHolder.wasConsumed())
            {
                    convertView.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                    convertView.setAlpha(1f); // A value higher of 0.9
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // or whatever color
            }
    }
```

Your problem is that you're reusing the same View, but you'll have the same alpha.
I would hold the state information in `ViewHolder` and not determine the state based on `convertView#alpha`

Comment: That did the trick. I missed that the `View`is reused. If possible, if you know, why is it that the system reuses the same object? I would have thought there would be one `View` for each row of the list.

Comment: @Eric Tobias Here you have a conference that google guys did 3 years ago and they speak about it, [GoogleI/O 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=3m10s)

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thank you very much for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

remove  `if (convertView == null)` condition and then try in getView()

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentViewGroup)
    {       
            FruitLoopsViewHolder viewHolder;
            final FruitLoopsNode FruitLoopsNode = provider.get(position);


                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parentViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_FruitLoops, null);

                viewHolder = new FruitLoopsViewHolder(
                                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time),
                                (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.consume),
                                (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail),
                                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_title),
                                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_brief),
                                (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar));
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        /** [Omitted some code setting many of the fields above to] */

        final Button button = viewHolder.getButton();
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        finalConvertView.setAlpha(0.5f);
                        finalConvertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
        });

        /**
         * As using a final viewHolder to set the value inside the onClick() method of the 
         * button will cause the images not to update anymore, investigating the alpha value
         * of the convertView seemed the only easy way to get there. Also, as it is a float, 
         * I want to leave a bit of extra padding in the test.
         */
        if(finalConvertView.getAlpha() < 0.9)
        {
                viewHolder.setConsumed(true);
        }

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove all the benefits of using a `ViewHolder` in the first place though?

Comment: Just to complete my previous comment; the documentation encourages the `null` check. Have a look at the documentation of the `getView()`method.

Comment: Yes, it will remove all benefits of ViewHolder. However I have also faced lot of problems with Listview though strange one. This approach solved my problem. Only use this approach if your list is small for large list items this is not recomended.